# SQL Calculate time difference between two times and show the hours

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I have currently in my table and when I run query between dates and for a specific `EmpNumber` this is what I get.

```
--------------------------------------------------- 
TransDateTime        TimeCardID    EmpNumber
---------------------------------------------------
2020-04-13 08:00        1984          79
2020-04-13 14:30        1984          79
2020-04-14 08:00        1984          79
2020-04-14 15:00        1984          79
---------------------------------------------------
```

What I am trying to achieve is

```
------------------------------------------------------------------ 
CheckInDateTime      CheckInDateTime    TotalHours     EmpNumber
------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-04-13 08:00     2020-04-13 14:30     6.5             79
2020-04-14 08:00     2020-04-14 15:00     7.0             79
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm using SQL Server 2014. Below is the query I am running:

```
SELECT
    A.TransDateTime as TransDate,
    B.TimeCardID as TimeCardID,
    (SELECT EmployeeID from [Employees] C WHERE C.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID) as EmpNumber,
    (SELECT LastName from [Employees] C WHERE C.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID) as EmpName,
    (SELECT FirstName from [Employees] C WHERE C.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID) as EmpID
FROM [Transactions] A
JOIN [TimeCardsTbl] B on A.TimeCardID = B.TimeCardID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another option

**Example**

```
Select TimeCardID
      ,EmpNumber
      ,CheckIn  = min(TransDateTime)
      ,CheckOut = max(TransDateTime)
      ,TotalHours = DateDiff(MINUTE,min(TransDateTime),max(TransDateTime)) / 60.0
 From ( 
        Select *
              ,Grp = (1+row_number() over (partition by EmpNumber,TimeCardID Order by TransDateTime)) / 2
         From YourTable
      ) A
 Group By TimeCardID,EmpNumber,Grp
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Note `datediff(MINUTE.,,,) /60.` can be off by up to 2 minutes.  Using `datediff(SECOND.,,,) /(60*60.0)`, would be accurate to the to a 2-second interval.  etc

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Yes very true., but having managed hotels and such, calculations were only to the minute.   I made an assumption.

Comment: @Sai Always happy to help.  FYI  ... I included TimeCardID because I would have employees with different rates.  For example, a desk clerk would also be a night auditor which had a higher rate,'

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

Use DATEDIFF:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2020-04-13 08:00', '2020-04-13 14:30')/60.0 AS DECIMAL(10,1))

SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CheckInDateTime, CheckInDateTime)/60.0 AS DECIMAL(10,1)) AS TotalHours
```

Since you are wanting fractional hours, then you will need to get the date difference in minutes; divide by 60; and then cast that to either a decimal or numeric datatype. The last step is important because if you do not cast to a decimal, and specify the number of decimal digits, then the result will be rounded.

More on DATEDIFF here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014

Comment: I understand the DateDiff function. How does the two rows get into single row with added column using the query you provided?

Comment: @Sai John's answer works. You can use a CTE as opposed to an inline view if you want. Both will get you the same result. I won't steal his code and take the credit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to compute the hour range. Then it's easy to get the time difference.

For example:

```
select  
  CheckInDateTime,
  CheckOutDateTime,
  datediff(second, CheckInDateTime, CheckOutDateTime) / 3600.0,
  EmpNumber
from (
  select
    convert(date, TransDateTime),
    EmpNumber,
    min(TransDateTime) as CheckInDateTime,
    max(TransDateTime) as CheckOutDateTime
  from t
  group by convert(date, TransDateTime)
) x
order by CheckInDateTime
```